# BufferedReader readLine() method returns boolean?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am writing a chat client in Java and getting a weird error message while trying to compile this in `Eclipse 4.4.1`:

```
            ...
            BufferedReader socketIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            ...
            String answer;
            while (answer = socketIn.readLine() != null) {
                incomingTextField.setText(answer);
            }
            ...
```

The error is:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to String

There is also appearing tip:

> Change type of 'answer' to 'boolean'

However, this makes no sense, as according to the documentation `readLine()` must return `String`.

Comment: Try putting parentheses like so `(answer = socketIn.readLine())`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need some () here:

```
while ((answer = socketIn.readLine()) != null) {
```

Check about [Operator Precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) to figure out why

Good Luck